# D'Alembert Solution - 1D Wave equation, integration step

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, wave-equation

I am working through D'Alembert's solution to the 1D wave equation using the substitution of canonical coordinates. I have an initial condition of: $$u_{t}(x,0) = g(x) $$ with a general solution containing the following two arbitrary functions: $$u(x,t) = \phi(x-ct) + \psi(x+ct)$$ These two functions are composite functions. I know I am supposed to take the partial derivative with respect to $t$ and set it equal to $g(x)$ to get the following: $$-c\phi'(x) + c\psi'(x) = g(x)$$ The book provides the above prime notation and does not specify what $\phi$ & $\psi$ are being differentiated by. The issue is the next step in the solution states to carry out the integration from $x_0$ to $x$ to obtain: $$ -c\phi(x) + c\psi(x) = \int^{x}_{x_0}g(\xi)d\xi +K$$ I believe my issue comes from correctly differentiating the composite function. At first I tried to just take the partial derivative with respect to $t$, setting $t=0$, and got the following: $$-c\frac{\partial{\phi(x)}}{\partial{t}} +c\frac{\partial{\psi(x)}}{\partial{t}} = g(x)$$ When I then integrate with respect to $x$ (the only way to make the integral of $g(\xi)$ make sense), I get the following: $$-c\int\frac{\partial{\phi(x)}}{\partial{t}}d(x) + ...$$ which doesn't make sense to me. So I then looked into if I was doing the partial derivative of the composite function incorrectly. I found some general texts online about derivatives of composite functions and got this: $$ h = g(f(x_1,x_2)) = g(u_1(x_1,x_2),u_2(x_1,x_2))$$ And using the chain rule for composite functions: $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial u_1} * \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial u_2} * \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1} $$ When I try to apply it to the problem, I get the following: $$ u(x,t) = g(f(x,t)) = g(\phi(x,t),\psi(x,t))$$ with the following derivative with respect to $t$: $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi} * \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \psi} * \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$$ which simplifies to (might be incorrect): $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -c * \frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi} + c * \frac{\partial u}{\partial \psi}$$ I don't know how to find $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi}$ or $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \psi}$ and those derivatives don't make sense when I try to integrate with respect to $x$: $$-c\int\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{\phi}}d(x) + ...$$ Can anyone show me where I am making a mistake in my understanding, and how to correctly differentiate $u(x,t) = \phi(x-ct) + \psi(x+ct)$ to get it into the correct form to where I can integrate with respect to $x$? Thank you!

Comment: Here the main idea to understand is that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are one variable functions, but they are evaluated in the point that is combined from other variables $x$ and $t$. So $\psi(x, t) = \psi(y(x, t))$, where $y = x + ct$.

Comment: So when after you see $-c\phi(x)+c\psi(x)=\int_{x_0}^x g(\xi)d\xi + K$ don't think about $x$ as spatial coordinate, this equality is true for any $x$. Write it for $w$ or $z$ variable. The letter you use is not significant.